# How to fetch all header request parameter in PHP

Tags: php, rest, http-headers, httprequest

I have created an API request and try to access the header parameter from that request using the `$_POST` method but didn't get header request data.

Here is my header request data:

```
Access-Key:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Content-Type:application/json
charset:utf-8
```

So how can I get fetch all header data using PHP? Can anybody help me?

Comment: try `getAllHeaders();`

Comment: i have tried with this but it doesn't Access-Key? other than that I get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$url = 'your url';
echo $type = get_headers($url, 1)["Access-Key"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use getallheaders() php function

getallheaders — Fetches all HTTP headers from the current request.

```
$headers =  getallheaders();
foreach($headers as $key=>$val){
  echo $key . ': ' . $val . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: i have tried with this but it doesn't Access-Key? other than that I get

Comment: @VishalPanchal what about $headers = apache_request_headers();

Comment: still missing Access_Key : XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Comment: @VishalPanchal try $_SERVER["Access-Key"]